# "variable" is read only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have the following code and I am getting error of "count" is read-only:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';

const CounterScreen = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => setCount(count++)} title="Increase" />
      <Button onPress={() => setCount(count--)} title="Decrease" />
      <Text>Current Counter: {count}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
export default CounterScreen;
```

But if I use `setCount(count + 1)` instead of `setCount(count++)`, it works perfectly. What is the difference here between `count + 1` and `count++`

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to remember is that **you can change the value of a variable declared as a const, but you cannot reassign it**. Here is a good blog post about this:

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const

setCount(count+1) is taking the current value of the variable count, adding 1 to it and then passing this to our setter function, 'setCount' to update our state. We are in no way reassigning the 'count' variable. React is updating the value of 'count' under the hood using the setter function.

What you are doing with count++ is attempting to re-assign the count variable, not just change the value of the 'count' variable.

Answer (score 0):

count++ is shorthand for `count = count + 1;` you are actually changing the value of a variable. not just reading its value.

Answer (score 0):

count++ is similar as `count = count + 1`
means it's changing the variable itself 
and you know `const` are read-only after initialization that is why you doing `setCount()` to update the value.

and `count + 1` is not updating itself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Your count in here ↑ is `read only`, if you want to change it's value have to call `setCount()`

Like `setCount(num)`

so if `num= 10` then equal to `setCount(10)`

So that `setCount(count + 1)` could work, `count+1` is a number

But why `setCount(count++)` couldn't work is because

```
count++
```

Equal to

```
count=count+1; //It is changing the value of count directly!
```

```
setCount(count++) 

setCount(count=count+1) //So count++ is changing the value of count directly, not through setCount, couldn't work.
```

It couldn't work and may error for `"count" is read-only`

This is try to change count value without calling `setCount` in `setCount`